# How do I find the name of the active worksheet without using ActiveSheet?

Tags: vba

Some of your folks advocate not using ActivateSheet. So how do I get the name of the active worksheet?

Comment: James, welcome to SO! :) Please, take [the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to earn your first shiny badge ;) Also, this question is too broad and i think it will be closed or ends with negative reputation.

Comment: Well if you want the name of the `ActiveSheet` why not `ActiveSheet.Name`? I don't think anybody claims that you should never use `ActiveSheet` -- just that you shouldn't overuse it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Selection.Parent.Name` However, that is even worse.

One reason to not use `Selection` or `ActiveSheet`is that while debugging, you might inspect other sheets or select other cells, and if you then continue with *F5* or *F8*, you will work on other data than foreseen.

But if the action taken by your code SHOULD depend on which sheet is currently active, just use `ActiveSheet`. (If you need it at the end of a Subroutine, or if you need it twice, however, consider assigning it to a variable at the beginning.